# Runtime button creation in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

This isn't so much a question about my specific code as it is a question on what I need to use to accomplish my task.

I'm making a workout logging app for my class. The user needs to be able to create a workout routine, filled with various exercises of their choice.

On the home page, there is an "Add Workout" button. Clicking this should bring them to a screen where they name the workout and fill it in with said exercises. When they click save, I need to be able to create a new button on the home page with simply the name of their new workout. This new button when clicked will bring them to that workout, where they can start the workout and put in their reps, sets, weight, etc.

What do I need to be looking at to achieve this? Do I need to be saving the workouts to a database and using a function to go through the database and populate the home screen with respective buttons each time I enter the app / add a new workout? Or is there a different way to do this? I'm not sure that I'm even asking the right question or framing this problem the correct way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put the button on the home page from the beginning but make it invisible at first.

yes you should put the workout information in a database and if there is a workout saved, make the button visible in the home page.

use `android:visibility="gone"` in XML and `birthday.visibility = View.VISIBLE` in the activity to modify the visibility

Comment: Awesome, thanks! In that case, would it be best to keep the number of workouts they can create to a certain size?

Comment: yes, you might need a recycler view if you want a different button for different workouts. if the answer was usefull to you can mark it as accepted question and upvote the answer?